Как заставить html распознавать гиперссылки в тексте? JS HTML CSS
У меня в проекте есть возможность оставлять комментарии и создавать статьи. Так вот, если пользователь введет ссылку, мне нужно, чтобы она отображалась кликабельной. Как это можно реализовать? Можете предлагать js, если это можно реализовать только через него.

Ищете через регулярные выражения ссылки, оборачиваете каждую в html-теги и заменяете изначальную на обернутую в теги

@rusgeli спасибо, попробую так

Если проект на Django, то в нём есть ckeditor, сам пользуюсь. Там имеется возможность вставлять ссылки, фотографии, код и редактировать текст.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
